# Microsoft DNS 'Virtual' subdomain?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-dns

I've been studying DNS, and would like to know if/how this is possible in MS DNS -

Say you have an AD domain - domain.com - in a main office. The subnets here might be **10.0.0.0/24 - 10.0.10.0/24**, but they all pull dhcp from the DC and become *hostx***.domain.com**.

**10.0.11.0/24** is a branch office (mpls/vpn) which isn't a part of the AD domain, and hosts there are configured with static IP's, and thus have to be referred to via IP address for administrative purposes.

Now let's say I'd like for there to be a **branch.domain.com** subdomain. Would it be possible to configure these devices to pull dhcp from the central server and receive fqdn's like *hostx***.branch.domain.com** ?

Or, even if I were to leave their static configurations intact, and just wanted to use DNS as a more convenient way to access remote devices - is it possible just to create a record that will point *hostx***.branch.domain.com** to that device?

*( The reason i'd rather not create a new dns host 'branch' is because in reality, there are >50 branches in our network, and the only devices on these networks are the printers, switches, etc., so that would be pretty inefficient. My first thoughts would be either to create aliases for the main DNS server and have it refer to itself for these lookups - Or maybe, to add just one more dns server, with an alias for each branch pointing to it, and use this secondary server to hand out dhcp to branch devices? **edit:** Or, would it be as simple as adding a forward lookup zone for each branch?)*

Answer (score 1):

You can add a zone for the subdomain branch.domain.com on the existing DNS server and pass the domain name via the respective DHCP option to the devices.